# NSUserDefualts data is duplicated many times in the Preferences folder

Tags: ios, ipad, plist, appdata

We are storing a xml config file which contains several key-value pairs in UserDefualts. The size of the .plist after the data is stored into the USerDefualts file is in between 5-50MB based on the user config file.

Recently in one of our beta devices, we found that the app Preferences  folder is of size 5GB which is 500 times more than the app size.

I downloaded the app .xcappdata for the beta device and found that the folder

```
AppData/Library/Preferences is 4.98GB
```

We have no idea why that folder is huge.

Inside that folder there are 800 of files with name in the format

```
(bundle-identifer).plist.1ESwPpG
```

`1ESwPpG` is the random string at the end of files.

And the size of each file shows 0 bytes.

There are two more additional files in this folder.

One is the app `.plist` (35MB) file and other one is `com.apple.EmojiCache.plist` (4KB).

Why the folder is over 4.5GB ?

I can delete the app and reinstall it which would solve the problem, it would be useful for us to know the cause of the issue.

I couldn't find much from https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/69830.

and [iOS app's Documents and Data becomes huge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886513/ios-apps-documents-and-data-becomes-huge)

**Note:** This app on the beta device hasn't been removed from the last 2-3 months. The app in the device is upgraded with every beta build.

**Note:** Deleting these files does reduce the folder size, but the file is showing 0 bytes when looked at file inspector window. Also the file shows nothing when opened by any text editor.

I see that the userdefault data .plist which is 35MB of size is duplicated many times which increase the folder size.

I'm wondering when exactly this happens.

Comment: In Terminal, it might be useful to try `ls -l@` on the folder to check for data in extended attributes.

Comment: wow, that comment is very helpful, now I can see which file is having more size.

Comment: @TomHarrington it looks like all my data shared in USerDefualts are been duplicated many times in these files.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure why that's happening or what it means.

Comment: You should not be storing app data in UserDefaults. Only use it to store little bits of preferences. Data should be stored elsewhere.

Comment: @rmaddy you dont suggest storing it in a separate .plist either ?

Comment: That's certainly one option. The UserDefaults plist file shouldn't be more than a few kilobytes in size, certainly not dozens of megabytes.